# Request which works and doesn't work

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, okhttp

I have a strange problem with POST using Retrofit. I have a  table `user` in DataBase with 4 columns: username, password, name, email.

This is my `sendPost` method:

```
public void sendPost(){
    User user = new User("a", "b", "c", "d");

    Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://MY_IP:8080/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());

    Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();

    Api api = retrofit.create(Api.class);
    retrofit2.Call<User> call = api.createUser(user);

    call.enqueue(new retrofit2.Callback<User>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(retrofit2.Call<User> call, retrofit2.Response<User> response) {
            Log.w("done", "done");
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(retrofit2.Call<User> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.w("fail", "fail");

        }
    });

}
```

.

```
public interface Api {

    @POST("users")
    Call<User> createUser(@Body User user);

}
```

.

```
public class User {

    String username;
    String password;
    String name;
    String email;

    public User(String username, String password, String name, String email){
            this.username = username;
            this.password = password;
            this.name = name;
            this.email = email;
    }


}
```

This method stops in method `onResponse`, and shows`done` in my Log, so it seems to work. But this request does nothing on the server.

I have used this method in other clients like Postman, and the user is added.

What could be wrong? What I should do with this request?

Comment: Please do not send passwords through an unencrypted request.

Comment: it is only test, I have other issue

Comment: can you check what you are receiving on the server

Comment: Try to send it to places like httpbin.org and in your `onResponse`, print the result. You may find that the problem maybe  code in your server.

Comment: You should be debugging the server code.

Comment: Just because you end in `onResponse` doesn't mean the request was successful. You might have received an http error. So check the status code of the response object. If it works in postman and not on retrofit 99% of the time I heard this is because postman automagically adds some headers that retrofit doesn't and the server cannot cope without them. So double check these too.